# How to check if values of an array are consecutively the same

Tags: javascript

**Task:**
I have to check if there are any two values consecutively same in an array. If it does. I have to take that repeated value into a different place to not have 2 identical values next to each other.

**Problem:**
It returns there are no identical values, when definitely there are more than one.
I know that this is happening because the "if" compares the first two elements and as they are not the same returns and stop the loop. But what I need is to complete the whole loop and if there are consecutive repeated values enter into the next loop.

I've tried to figure it out solution and genuinely understand it for a long time, and I couldn't.

**What I've tried:** (I am working with a Stack, I will not post the methods of it because I know they are working fine for other exercises)

```
function noIdenticalConsecutives(arr) {

  let stack = new Stack();
  let repeat = [];

  if (arr.length === 0) return "No values to iterate";

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    const curr = arr[i];
    const next = arr[i + 1];

    if (curr !== next) return "There are no identical consecutive values";
  }

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i] === arr[i+1]){
      repeat.push(arr[i])
  }else{
    stack.push(arr[i])
  }
}

  for (let i = 0; i < repeat.length; i++) {
    const element = repeat[i];
    stack.push(element);
  }
  return stack;
}

noIdenticalConsecutives([14, 4, 10, 7, 3, 1, 1, 5, 7, 7]);//There are no identical values
```

Comment: Return that there are no values only when you have iterated through the entire array and haven't spotted a single repeating consecutive number. You might want to create a boolean (false by default) that will help you with that. When you spot a repeating number change the boolean to true. After the loop is finished if the boolean is false return that there are no repeating values.

Comment: *" have to take that repeated value into a different place to not have 2 identical values next to each other."* That's a little vague. So what is the result supposed to be and what do you actually get when input array is `[14, 4, 10, 7, 3, 1, 1, 5, 7, 7]`?

Comment: Do you mean the final result is [1, 7]? different place means another array?

Comment: The result of that array should be [14, 4, 10, 7, 3, 1, 5, 7, 1 , 7] 
that is why I send the repeat one into a new array, loop through it and push them back to the stack

Comment: @TitanXP 

The result of that array should be [14, 4, 10, 7, 3, 1, 5, 7, 1 , 7] that is why I send the repeating values into a new array called "repeat", loop through it and push them back to the stack.

Comment: So the result is the same array but all consecutive repeated numbers are pushed to the end of the array?

Comment: @zer00ne Yes. The task in here is to not have same values next to each other.

Comment: Ok, you have to filter out the repeated elements then concat with the filtered array. I have written the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is wrong. in the First case when (14 != 4) this will return no identical values. hence your code will stop on the first case and didn't check further.

You can correct your algo. by modifying this-

```
let isIdentical = false;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
const curr = arr[i];
const next = arr[i + 1];

if (curr == next) { isIdentical = true; return; }
}
if(!isIdentical){ return "There are no identical consecutive values";}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first you have to separate out the repeated elements into another array then concat it with the filtered array.

```
function noIdenticalConsecutives(arr) {
  let stack = [];
  let repeat = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i + 1] !== arr [i]) {
      stack.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      repeat.push(arr[i]);
    };
  };
  return stack.concat(repeat);
};

console.log(noIdenticalConsecutives([14, 4, 10, 7, 3, 1, 1, 5, 7, 7]));
// [14, 4, 10, 7, 3, 1, 5, 7, 1, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have prematurely returned. This should fix the problem

```js
function noIdenticalConsecutives(arr) {
  let stack = new Stack();
  let repeat = [];
  let hasRepeat = false;

  if (arr.length === 0) return "No values to iterate";

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    const curr = arr[i];
    const next = arr[i + 1];

    if (curr === next) hasRepeat = true;
    
  }
  if (!hasRepeat) return "There are no identical consecutive values";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing you can replace all the code above using one single array.reduce like that:

```
const stackAndRepeat = arr.reduce((accumulator, next) => {
    accumulator.stack[accumulator.stack.length - 1] === next ? accumulator.repeat.push(next) : accumulator.stack.push(next);

    return accumulator;
}, { stack: [], repeat: [] });
```

Now stackAndRepeat.stack and stackAndRepeat.next should contain the correct values for you.

Answer (score 0):

This version uses recursion in order to handle 2 or more consecutive numbers (ex. `[4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 8, 8]`). It also stops immediately should there be too many consecutive numbers. Details are commented in example.

```js
const noConsecutives = array => {
  let repeats = array.reduce((rep, now, idx, arr) => {   
    // If the previous number equals the current number...
    if (arr[idx-1] === now) {
      // remove the current number...
      let match = arr.splice(idx, 1);
      // and add it to the accumulator array
      rep.push(match[0]);
    }
    // Always remember to return accumulator 
    return rep;
  }, []);
  // If repeats array is empty...
  if (repeats.length < 1) {
    // return message and end function
    return "There are no consecutive numbers";
  }
  // If repeats array is greater or equal to the input array...
  if (repeats.length >= array.length) {
    // return input array
    return "Too many consecutive numbers";
  }
  // Merge the input array with repeats array
  let result = [...array, ...repeats]
  // While there is any consecutive numbers in result array...
  while (result.some((num, idx, arr) => arr[idx-1] === num && idx !== 0)) {
    // recursively call noConsecutives() passing result array
    result = noConsecutives(result);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(noConsecutives([0, 1, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 6, 0, 9, 2, 0, 0, 7])));
console.log(noConsecutives([4, 4, 4, 4]));
console.log(noConsecutives([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]));
```